# Lost with django-social-auth and custom oauth2 backen

Tags: django, django-socialauth

This may not be a very good stackoverflow question because I am so lost I think my question will appear like I have made no effort.

I want to get the user's email from Xero, a cloud accounting app which specifically allows for this (https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/sign-in)

When I create a Xero "app" to get the necessary credentials, I need to provide an OAuth 2.0 redirect URI, and I think this is very common or even universal for oauth2 authentication.
I can't see an example of how I provide this URL to the configuration of my backend (a subclass of BaseOAuth2). Apart from being a redirect URL, it must also be provided in the AUTHORIZATION_URL.

The Xero URL template is https://login.xero.com/identity/connect/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=YOURCLIENTID&redirect_uri=YOURREDIRECTURI&scope=email&state=1234

I have read quite a few tutorials. I can't find any on adding a custom oauth2 backend, but in this tutorial there are examples for GitHub and Twitter:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html

In both cases, the tutorial says to provide a callback URL of the form http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/twitter/ when defining the app on the authenticator's side.

Is this a hard-coded, undocumented default? Or do I need to define it somewhere in my configuration? In the tutorial, I can't see any reference to a callback url in the backend code for github.py or twitter.py.

So I am lost because I don't know my Django app handles the redirect from Xero if I don't tell it what the redirecting URL will be, and I don't know how a custom backend can elegantly create a valid auth URL because it needs to have a redirect URL provided. I can't find documentation on this that I can understand, and I can't work it out from the source code.

Comment: The callback url is provided in the tutorial, it is the line `url(r'^oauth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),` in the `urls.py` file. This endpoint contains all these callback URLs related to Github, Twitter, or any other service.

Answer (score 1):

Tutorial explains how to use OAuth providers already available in the [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#features) plugin. Check the [provided](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#features) page for the list of available integrations.

What you really need here is to add your custom provider plugin for the Xero service. You can use [this manual](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/index.html#adding-new-backend-support) for adding a new backend.

Comment: thanks. My biggest problem was not understanding how it worked, so I have implemented login with Xero from scratch (fetching the code, decoding the token, finding the user and doing the login). Now that I know how it works in more detail, I will try again  with a custom provider from python-social-auth.